# Inserting to a textbox with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to insert text into a textbox using Tkinter. I'm trying to insert information retrieved from a file but I've boiled it down to something simpler which exhibits the same problem:

```
class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def helloCallBack(self):
        self.txt.insert("lol")

    def init_ui(self):    
        self.txt = Text(root, width=24, height = 10).grid(column=0, row = 0)

        load_button = Button(root, text="Load Wave Data", command = self.helloCallBack).grid(column=1, row = 0, sticky="E")

def main():
    ex = Main(root)
    root.geometry("300x250+300+300")
    root.mainloop()
```

What I want it to do is whenever I press the button it inserts `lol` into the text box but I get the error

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need to call `grid` in separated line. Because the method return `None`; causing the `self.txt` to reference `None` instead of `Text` widget object.

   ```
   def init_ui(self):
       self.txt = Text(root, width=24, height=10)
       self.txt.grid(column=0, row=0)

       load_button = Button(root, text="Load Wave Data", command=self.helloCallBack)
       load_button.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="E")
   ```
2. You need to specify where to insert the text.

   ```
   def helloCallBack(self):
       self.txt.insert(END, "lol")
   ```

Answer (score 3):

To insert you need to indicate where you want to start inserting text:

```
self.txt.insert(0, "lol")
```